# How to get Matrix subtotal to the first column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix where different KPI's are coming from different tables
Example:

```
      India   China   USA   Australia  Total
KPI1  2       3       4     5          14
KPI2  1       2       3     4          10
KPI3  8       10      10    8          36
```

The total column is COLUMN SUBTOTALS to ON in the MATRIX VISUAL and SHOW ON ROW is ON since the data in the base file had to be transposed in order to get this "look".

I want to get this column to the front but according to Power BI Community answers, it is currently not possible.

I was thinking of making a CALCULATED COLUMN or a MEASURE for this task but I don't know how to make it possible since these KPI are coming from different tables.

Any help on this is very much appreciated or some other workaround?

EDIT

SAMPLE DATA

```
Teams | Country | KPI 1
    A | India   | 3
```

in the same way, all KPIs are stored in different sheets of the excel file.

OUTPUT

```
     Total India   China    USA   Australia  
KPI1  14     2       3       4     5          
KPI2  10     1       2       3     4          
KPI3  36     8       10      10    8
```

Comment: You need to show your sample data from all tables and then explain/show your expected output from the raw data.

Comment: @mkRabbani thank you for your suggestion. I have made the edits. Could you please check ?

Comment: What you have done so far? is there any issue you are facing?

Comment: @mkRabbani I have tried moving the column subtotals to the front but there is no option available like that. Also I tried using the SUM function but since most of the KPI's are MEASURES, I am unable to form any MEASURE or a CALCULATED column in Power BI for calculating its subtotals.

Comment: What do you mean by Front?

Comment: @mkRabbani I thought I was clear when I produced the sample output. Anyway, I have to get my column SUBTOTAL to the FRONT(first column) instead of BEHIND (last column)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225961/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-coder-bg).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple way to move the total column to the left, at least in the current version of Power BI (as of when this answer was written).

There is a workaround but it's a bit of a pain. Instead of using automatic subtotals, you create "Total" rows in your data tables as if it were any other country.

Once Total exists as a country, you add an index column to define the display order using the [Sort by Column button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column) so that Total appears first.

Both appending the total data rows and adding the country ordering index should probably be done in the query editor.